# How to connect a show/hide and scrollit

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I make gallery on my onepage website. I try use show/hide and scrollit 
to show more details about my work. But I do not know how to connect it together to make it work.

Here code gallery. When I push it open information about it.

```html
<li>
  <a href="#single-project" class="show_hide more" rel="#slidingDiv8" >
    <div class="item web-design" data-ref="mixitup-target"> 
      <img src="img/1.png" alt="project 9">
    </div>
    <div class="caption">
      <div class="blur"></div>
      <div class="caption-text">
        <h6>Amazing Caption</h6>
        <p>Whatever It Is - Always Awesome</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </a>
</li>
```

Here is Scrolit which I want to put in the code above.

```html
<li><a data-scroll-nav='4'></a></li>
```

In the start div i have add

```html
<section data-scroll-index='4'>
```

How do I connect them show/hide and scrollit to work together? Trying for some time and will only show/hide but not scroll.

Comment: So, try to learn JavaScript. Then, you can easily figure it out. The fact is, in `StackOverFLow` we try to help each other fix the issues or improve the coding. Not providing some codes from the scratch or teaching individually

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to use Jquery toggle class ? If yes, Jquery trigger can be call like this `$(selector).toggle(speed,callback);`

Hope this helps

https://jsfiddle.net/pq8ef3dw/